# How to get the content type of a file-zend?

Tags: php, zend-framework, content-type

I have

```
$tmpname = $file_temp_name;
$filename = $file_name;
$tmppath = "http://" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . "/uploads/" . $tmpname;
```

How can i get its content type from these data..?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using PHP 5.3 or later, you could use the [FileInfo extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php):

```
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
$mimeType = finfo_file($finfo, $filename);
finfo_close($finfo);
```

Hope that helps,